# Can I put a <span> tag in the Text property of an ASP:Button?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to do something like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" 
            runat="server" 
            CssClass="greybtn" 
            Text='<span>Search</span>'
            OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />
```

It displays `<span>Search</span>` instead of just `Search`.

Comment: Why do you need something like this in the first place?

Comment: I know it is stupid, I am tyring something out for the heck of it and was just curious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't put markup inside a button. An asp:Button control just renders as an input button HTML tag: `<input type="button" value="<span>Search</span>" />` (technically `value="&lt;span&gt;Search&lt;/span&gt;" />`). The browser treats the contents of the `value` attribute as a literal string.

However, you **can** put markup inside a `<button><span>Search</span></button>` (you can put quite a bit of HTML in there, including images). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187482/how-can-i-use-the-button-tag-with-aspnet) talks about building a control which emits the `button` tag.

Answer (score 14):

You can put a span on an ASP.NET LinkButton like this:-

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="TestLinkButton" CssClass="btn btn-success" runat="server"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"/>Press Me</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Best answer in my opinion. Is there any reason to use a Button over a LinkButton? Or essentially, any unwanted side effects from doing it this way?

Comment: Sorry only just spotted this comment for some reason. A link button and a button are two different things. link button generates an "a" tag, a button is an "input" tag which is usually used for submitting forms (although ASP.NET webforms hides this a bit, you can click them and call click events in webforms). This is really another question so I'm not going to go on.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a asp linkButton for this:

Answer (score 0):

No. It renders a  tag, so whatever you put in the Text property gets rendered as that button's value.

Answer (score 0):

The text property will automatically turn `<` and `>` into the entities `&lt;` and `&gt;`.  More than that, button renders to html as an `input` element, with the text set in it's `value` property.

Do you maybe want a HyperLink or Label control instead?