# postback fires even after returning false from OnClientClick

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I need to Stop Button1_Click fire after Jquery function return false..This is my Code ...

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/Javascript/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/a.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script runat="server">

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="return x();"  OnClick="Button1_Click" />
            OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

js File

```
function x() {

    alert('');

    return false;
}
```

this is my HTML generated File

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/Javascript/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/a.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>

</title></head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="Default.aspx" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTExNTM0OTE4ODNkZI8CSkltDp/afauc6DGl2D8JvNnVI1ffgzykF0L2alVM" />
</div>

<div class="aspNetHidden">

    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEdAAOSROoMi8eHXeBzZ77oKwMrESCFkFW/RuhzY1oLb/NUVM34O/GfAV4V4n0wgFZHr3eJjGQabRwzK4TIMzE2tX2gN9468Yg/u6i/oj/9EvNo1w==" />
</div>
    <div>
        <input name="TextBox1" type="text" id="TextBox1" />
        <input type="submit" name="Button1" value="Button" onclick="return x();" id="Button1" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I also tried Similar links :

[Why doesn't returning false from OnClientClick cancel the postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812168/why-doesnt-returning-false-from-onclientclick-cancel-the-postback)

In this case a handler for the one more  click event was registered via jquery ..I think it is not in my case

[ASP.NET OnClientClick="return false;" doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893963/asp-net-onclientclick-return-false-doesnt-work?lq=1)

there should not be a click event handler (registered via jquery) which returns true .whats mean by that ?Does it mean that i need to remove onClick function ... i dont wanna do it

I also tried other suggested Code :

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"  OnClientClick="if (!x()) return     
false;"  OnClick="Button1_Click" /> 

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="javascript:return        
x();"OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

they are also not working

Plese suggest

Comment: Can you post the generated HTML source?

Comment: Please show `JS` code for function `X` ??

Comment: I uploaded Both Files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me...
***.aspx page***

```
<asp:Button id="btn" runat="server" Text="Button" onclientclick="if (!x()) { return false; }" onclick="btn_Click" />
<script type="text/javascript">
   function x() {
      return false;
   }
</script>
```

<kbd>[Reference Help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3171836/2260614)</kbd>

---

**Update** from an external javascript file working code
*external.js*

```
function x() {
    var result = confirm("Sure");
    if (result)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

*.aspx page*

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:Button id="btn" runat="server" Text="Button" onclientclick="if (!x()) { return false; }" onclick="btn_Click" />
</form>
<script src="external.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Hope it helps..!!

Comment: Yup...It also worked for me for inline Script .. Still thinking why not working for External js file .. anyway thanks

Answer (score 1):

*You can also put all the code in single file. Attaching handler directly from jQuery*

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            AttachDeleteButtonHandler();
        });

        function AttachDeleteButtonHandler() {
            var btnDelete = $("div[class='page']").find("table[id$='tblButtons']").find("input[id$='btnDelete']");
            btnDelete.click(
                function () {
                    return ConfirmDelete();
                }
            );
        }

        function ConfirmDelete() {
            var msg = $('div[id="hdnElements"]').find('span[onclick*="translatedMsgText"]').text();
            if (confirm(msg)) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```