# onServerClick when javascript disabled

Tags: javascript, html, button, server-side

I'm trying to get an html button to call a server-side method like this:

```
<button onserverclick="onClick" runat="server">Submit</button>
```

However, this call is not being made when the browser's javascript is disabled.

I am confused because my understanding is that this call has no interaction with javascript.

Comment: So this works when JavaScript is enabled?

Comment: It works fine when JavaScript is enabled

Comment: What server-side language/framework are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `__doPostBack()` method is responsible for raising a click event to the server in the background. With JavaScript disabled there's no way that's going to happen.

Here's one of the many articles that explains [how this works](http://www.evagoras.com/2011/02/10/how-postback-works-in-asp-net/). And a [related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245033/asp-net-onserverclick-event-handler-not-called-if-using-onclick) which gives a glimpse into what code is generated behind the scenes.

Comment: I see, thanks! How then would I go about submitting a form to the server without JavaScript?

Comment: @blackconstant: Use the plain `action` attribute on the form. Also, You could also use the [noscript](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp) HTML tag. Maybe to display a message to the user, at least?