# Anchor tag onserverclick not working

Tags: html, asp.net

I am not sure why i am not able to call the server side event. Any help would be much appreciated:

```
<li>
    <a href="" runat="server" onserverclick="btnRoomsForRentCount_Click">
        <span class="fg1">2345</span><span class="nu1">Rooms for rent</span>
    </a>
</li>


protected void btnRoomsForRentCount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245033/asp-net-onserverclick-event-handler-not-called-if-using-onclick

Answer (score 1):

Actually I found the code part you have provided here, is working perfect. It can be the problem with the any remaining part of code. Please check the rest of your code.

All the best...