# "Fancy Button" Click Event not firing

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am working on a fancy design for a ASPX page, but I am having problems firing the buttons to run code. Here's what I have:

This is the ASPX code:

```
<button runat="server" id="btnLogin" onserverclick="LoginClick_Click"></button>
```

And the codebehind:

```
protected void LoginClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        notice.Visible = true;


   //     Response.Redirect("");

    }
```

I am clicking the button to see if anything shows up (even to a Blank broken page [yes I uncommented it]) but no go. I believe this is something simple but I've been struggling here for nearly an hour and no go. Joys of coding I guess.

Edit:

```
 <button runat="server" id="btnLogin" OnServerClick="btnLogin_Click" ></button>
```

That worked. Capitalization it seems.

Comment: Does the page post back? Can you put a breakpoint on the handler and see if it stops there?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245033/asp-net-onserverclick-event-handler-not-called-if-using-onclick

Check that post.

Comment: Yes, it postbacks. Page Load breakpoint activates but not the button event.

Comment: Just tried the setup in basic ASPX/CS - it works as designed. Are u sure you're clicking correct button that is wired to correct event handler? What other controls are on the page?

Comment: That's weird. Yeah, I verified. I added a normal button for testing purposes and the postback happened perfectly. Weird.

Comment: Ugh, I believe it was the capitalization. OP edited.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more careful with your syntax.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" id="btnLogin" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" />
```

Code behind

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        notice.Visible = true;
    }
```

Comment: I am not using ASP's built in buttons. Its a straight HTML button.

Comment: Unless... am I supposed to input <asp.Button ... in a regular HTML buton?

Comment: You have indicated this question deals with ASP.NET Web Forms. Therefore, you should use the controls provided. The asp:Button is specifically made for calling a function on the server side. Unless you have a specific reason for not using ASP.NET controls, I suggest you use them.

Comment: I can use an ImageButton (its an Image) but I lose CSS/JQuery effects I want to have.

Comment: @LordRelix You can apply CSS and jQuery effects to an ASP.NET button or ImageButton. You should not let that stop you from using the correct control.

Comment: Really? Didn't know that. I thought they were mostly static controls. Will look into that, didn't know it was possible.

Comment: While I agree that WebControls (instead of HtmlControls) should be used where possible, there is nothing 'wrong' with using plain vanilla HTML controls in a WebForms scenario, which is why controls in the System.Web.UI.HtmlControls namespace exists; in some scenarios (legacy apps etc) it may not be possible to upgrade everything to WebControls. To the OP - to eliminate the possibility of capitalization problems, wire up your events in Page Init instead; that way there's no possibility of capitalization problems, because the handler declaration is not in the markup.

Answer (score 0):

If you're really interested in using a different button from an ASP control, you might want to just poke a hidden ASP button with the desired functionality using some inline javascript and jquery...

```
<asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Visible="False" />
<button type="button" id="btnFancy" onclick="serverClick();">TextHere</button>
```

--

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function serverClick() {
    $('#<%=btnLogin.ClientID%>').click();
    }
</script>
```

I wouldn't suggest this, but it should work for you.