# OnClick is not working for input type submit

Tags: c#

```
<input type="submit" id="BtnForgotpswd" runat="server" style="cursor: pointer;" name="forgot"
 class="login loginmodal-submit" onserverclick="ImgBtnForgotPassword_Click" />

protected void ImgBtnForgotPassword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //somecode
}
```

I have given the code like the above but the code behind function is not firing.

Comment: try to change type='submit' to type='button', perhaps type submit is submiting by default, not firing onclick event

Comment: Try OnClick="ImgBtnForgotPassword_Click" instead. You may find additional info in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245033/asp-net-onserverclick-event-handler-not-called-if-using-onclick

Comment: If I give the type as button then the required field validator is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You better try out onsubmit method

```
 <form onsubmit="doThis()">
     <input type="submit" value="Click here">
 </form>
```