# Use CSS button styles for ASP.NET input buttons?

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I know there must be a simple answer I'm overlooking here . . . I have an ASP.NET application and I'm using an HTML template I bought. The template has CSS definitions for buttons like (note there is no class defined)

```
<button type="submit">
```

But I'm using ASP.NET buttons which render like

```
<input type="submit">
```

How can I make it so that the two buttons render in the same way? I need the input tag to have the same formatting as the button tag

Comment: And you're unable to edit your template or what exactly is the problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use the button tag with ASP.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187482/how-can-i-use-the-button-tag-with-asp-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not too trivial, but there's a way to do it ([**Article Here**](http://www.delphicsage.com/home/blog.aspx/d=239/title=Convert_Your_ASPButton_Controls_to_Sliding_Doors_Styled_Button_Elements_))

Basically, you need to implement a control adapter and get a .browser file to have your application render it that way. Take a look on the article.

Comment: Oy vey! Thank for your answer, this looks like what I'm looking for. But you're certainly right, it's far from trivial like I was hoping!

Comment: .browser files and control adapters are no longer supported by Microsoft. Tag mapping maybe?