# Submit form after asp:RegularExpressionValidator check form valid?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a form with this markup:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMeMail" runat="server" Width="250px" ToolTip="error"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator CssClass="mandatory msg" ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="validEmail" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" ControlToValidate="txtMeMail" ErrorMessage="error" EnableClientScript="true" />
<button class="button noMarginLeft" runat="server" validationgroup="validEmail" accesskey="S" id="btnSave" onserverclick="BtnSave_Click" value="Page.FIUserEdit.SaveButton.Label">
    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="label"></asp:Label>
</button>
```

When I input "abc" and remove the focus from the text box, the invalid email message shows up. After that, I correct the text box with a valid email and I keep the focus on the text box, then I click the submit button. The validation message disappears but the form does not submit.

Is there any way to validate and then submit the form?

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
<asp:Button class="button noMarginLeft" runat="server" ValidationGroup="validEmail" accesskey="S" ID="btnSave" OnServerClick="BtnSave_Click" value="Page.FIUserEdit.SaveButton.Label" />
```

The problem is that you use the ordinary html Button tag. Although it can work it is not recommended because you lose functionality, see [How can I use the button tag with ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187482/how-can-i-use-the-button-tag-with-asp-net)

If you do want content inside the button then use the LinkButton.

Comment: It works if you replace `OnServerClick` by `OnClick`. :-)

Comment: If I try that the button still does a postback even when the email is invalid.

Comment: still not working, I debug the javascript and see that on change event of the text box return true, and the submit was not call.

Comment: Think I find out the root cause was when the validate message show up, it make the submit button moving, and my click not on the button.